# Time picker customisation

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, timepicker

Project has the design of time picker dialog.

the design as follows

[image: design image]

then default dialog design is like below

[image: default design]

I want the top section of this time picker dialog should be same as the expected design.

I have tried following xml code. nothing helped.

```
  <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePicker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numbersBackgroundColor="#ddd"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:headerTimeTextAppearance="@drawable/bg_time"
        android:headerAmPmTextAppearance="@color/yellow"
        android:amPmBackgroundColor="@color/yellow"
        android:headerBackground="@android:color/transparent"
        />
```

And I have added following code to set the title color to transparent. so that I can put my view on the top section.

```
 android:headerTextColor = "@android:color/transparent"
```

but it says and threw the error

> "Unknown Attribute android:headerTextColor"

. in the design part of the XML layout, it set the transparent color to title. but when I run the app it threw the error of

> "Android resource linking failed".

Answer (score 0):

Use [Material TimePicker](https://material.io/components/time-pickers) to achieve the following design

```
 val picker = MaterialTimePicker.Builder()
            .setTimeFormat(TimeFormat.CLOCK_12H)
            .setHour(12)
            .setMinute(10)
            .setTitleText("Select Appointment time")
            .build()
```

To show dialog

```
picker.show(supportFragmentManager, picker.toString())
```

Using theme attributes and styles in `res/values/styles.xml` to change color according to your need:

```
<style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.*">
    ...
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/shrine_pink_100</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/shrine_pink_900</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/shrine_pink_100</item>
    <item name="chipStyle">@style/Widget.App.Chip</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: how can I use it on xml layout. because don't want dialog. it should be in fragment itself.

Comment: I don't think you can use it in xml, but you can make it fullscreen if that helps

Answer (score 0):

This is material 3 design and for material 3 design you have to use the following attributes to change the colors and use appropriate/required colors.

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.PChart.Material3TimePicker" parent="ThemeOverlay.Material3.MaterialTimePicker">
    <item name="colorSurface">@color/white_fade</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurfaceVariant">@color/darkCyan</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/gray_faded_AA</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/darkCyan</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimaryContainer">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryContainer">@color/darkCyan</item>
</style>
```

and in kotlin code set this as theme

```
val picker =
        MaterialTimePicker.Builder()
            .setTheme(R.style.ThemeOverlay_PChart_Material3TimePicker)
            .setInputMode(INPUT_MODE_CLOCK)
            .setTimeFormat(TimeFormat.CLOCK_24H)
            .setHour(initialHour)
            .setMinute(initialMinute)
            .setTitleText(title)
            .build()
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a custom style in themes.xml. And then set that theme/style to your time picker in xml. This is example of a style:

```
<style name="MyTimePickerWidgetStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.TimePicker">
    <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/stayGray</item>
    <item name="android:numbersTextColor">#fff</item>
    <item name="android:numbersInnerTextColor">#fff</item>
    <item name="android:numbersSelectorColor">@color/stayGray</item>
    <item name="android:amPmTextColor">#fff</item>
</style>
```

This is how you set style to time picker in xml.

```
<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/timePickerGoal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/MyTimePickerWidgetStyle"
    style="@style/MyTimePickerWidgetStyle"/>
```